# Login using Http Post android given custom api

Tags: android, authentication, http-post

I am trying to login to a site using a login form and submit button in my app. I have been given the following api information:

the api has been set up at  [consumer.api.mobodev.terryinc.com](http://consumer.api.terrydev.terryinc.com)

Using this api I am trying to login using a username. The following information has been provided for the api call:

> Login with Username The Login with Username service is provided for
>   existing Consumers to login using their username and password. The
>   username will be either an email address or mobile phone number
>   depending on how the Consumer had initially registered.  Login with
>   Username will typically be used when logging into a second or
>   subsequent Device, or via the browser etc.  This is because in the
>   normal process flow, a Consumer will register and the Access Token
>   will be returned and cache by the Client Application.  The Access
>   Token is then used when starting the application instead of getting
>   the Consumer to log in again. Calling the Login with Username logs the
>   Consumer into the system and creates and returns a valid OAuth Access
>   Token.  The returned OAuth Access Token can then be used in for
>   subsequent API calls to identify the Consumer of the Client
>   Application. Attributes 
>   Attribute Value

- Path /v3/logins Support
- Formats JSON, XML HTTP
- Method POST
- Secure No
- Rate Limited
- No Cache
- Timeout TBC 
  -HTTP Codes 200 - OK 
  400 - Bad Request.
  500 - Internal Server Error.

Below is the code that I have written in the main activity:

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

**HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("consumer.api.mobodev.terryinc.com");**


    try {
        // Add user name and password
     EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
     String username = uname.getText().toString();

     EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
     String password = pword.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type","password"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        Log.w("Post", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        Log.w("Before Post", str.toString());
```

My question is did I use the correct url when creating my httpPost object?

Please help as I have no idea how to interpret the api documentation.

Comment: As the host consumer.api.mobodev.terryinc.com is not even reachable, the info they gave to you seems to be wrong or they do not provide that service anymore. If it is reachable from your destination/in your network, please share with us what you get as a response. From my experience REST endpoints are typically not the hostnames but a specific path, in your case that could perhaps be http://consumer.api.terrydev.terryinc.com/v3/logins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox, there's this awesome add-on I use to simulate and test API calls - it's called [Rest Client](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/), and I recommend you test the apis here first before you code anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot... RestClient is truely amazing, once u get the hang of it.